# Python Search The String in a Array List

Tags: python, c, arrays, struct

```
StructPageNum = namedtuple('FDResult', ['DeviceID', 'PageNum'])
PageNumList = []
Node = StructPageNum(DeviceID='NR0951113', PageNum=[1,2,3,4])
PageNumList.append(Node)
Node = StructPageNum(DeviceID='NR0951114', PageNum=[1,2,3,4])
PageNumList.append(Node)

print('NR0951113' in PageNumList[:].DeviceID)
```

1)how to search NR0951113 whether in the PageNumList or not?

### EDITED

2)if i want to get the NR0951113 array index?how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want:

```
any(x.DeviceID == 'NR0851113' for x in PageNumList)
```

If you actually want to get the index, then possibly [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) is the builtin you should be using:

```
next(i for i,x in enumerate(PageNumList) if x.DeviceID == 'NR085113')
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if the DeviceID isn't found on any of your objects.  You can prevent the `StopIteration` by passing a second value to `next` which is returned if the iterable you pass in is empty:

```
index = next((i for i,x in enumerate(PageNumList) if x.DeviceID == 'NR085113'),None)
if index is not None:
    ...
```

Comment: if i want to get the NR0951113 array index?how to get it?

Comment: @C.Y Updated.  To get that info, you'll need `next`

Comment: if i want to modify PageNumList.PicData.insert(0,''), how to do that?

Comment: @C.Y -- The short answer is that you don't ... `namedtuple` are still `tuple` and therefore immutable.  You could probably construct a *new* `namedtuple` and put it into `PageNumList` from the data in the old one (replacing the old one while you're at it) ... depending on what you're doing, this might be a good subject for a new question.

Comment: New Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731157/python-how-to-edit-array-namedtuples-data