# Python how to edit data in a namedtuple stored in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, struct, namedtuple

```
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

StructPageNum = namedtuple('FDResult', ['DeviceID', 'PageNum','PicSize','PicData'])
PageNumList = []

Node = StructPageNum(DeviceID='NR09', PageNum=[],PicSize=100,PicData='')
PageNumList.append(Node)

PageNumList[0].PicData = 'hello' //how to do at here?
```

### QUESTION

how to edit the value of PicData?

Comment: because python is like C

Comment: No, it's not like C. For one thing line comments start with `#` not `//`

Comment: Tuples are immutable data structures, so you can't replace the value, only create a new tuple with that value changed.

Comment: The problem is you're using an immutable tuple and then trying to updated it -- your only option is to replace the whole thing or use a different data type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me like you can use the [`_replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) method of a namedtuple to do this pretty easily:

```
PageNumList[0] = PageNumList[0]._replace(PicData='hello')
```

This puts a *new namedtuple* in your `PageNumList` which looks pretty much like the old namedtuple except that we've changed the `PicData` "attribute".  You can't edit the namedtuple that you have already since `namedtuple`s are immutable (just like their unnamed counterparts: `tuples`)

Comment: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression ?

Comment: @C.Y -- Sorry, over-zealously quoted :)

Comment: ya,just read the _replace document,just figure out, anyway thanks!

Comment: To elaborate slightly, you *cannot* edit a `namedtuple`, they're immutable.  `_replace()` returns a new tipple with

Comment: @mgilson can leave a contact? you are damn cool.just for contact purpose,not for asking question.question i will post at here,cheer!

Comment: @mgilson if i want to _replace the PageNum, PageNum is a array,i want to append the array,how to do it?

Comment: Solved PageNumList[0].PageNum.append(16)

Comment: Yep.  You're free to mutate mutable objects which are stored in immutable objects.  I always found that to be a bit interesting.  Also, FWIW, note that `tuple` are only hashable if they contain only hashable items.